# Ruby Struct: replace nil value with space

Tags: ruby

I need to ensure no nil or empty values are inside a Struct, when nil I would like to replace it with a space but the following doesn't work.

Is this possible and how ? Thanks..

```
s = Struct.new(:datum, :string1, :string2, :string3, :nummer)
r = s.new(Time.now(), "", "test", nil, 0.0)

p r

r.each do |a|
    a.replace(" ") if a.class == String && a.empty?
    a = " " if a.nil?
end

p r
```

before:

```
#<struct datum=2017-03-14 15:28:40 +0100, string1="", string2="test", string3=nil, nummer=0.0>
```

after:

```
#<struct datum=2017-03-14 15:28:40 +0100, string1=" ", string2="test", string3=nil, nummer=0.0>
```

wanted:

```
#<struct datum=2017-03-14 15:28:40 +0100, string1=" ", string2="test", string3=" ", nummer=0.0>
```

Comment: What is wrong with my answer? Also, never do explicit comparison of classes, use `var.is_a?(String)` instead.

Comment: Of course empty string `""` **is indeed replaced** with my code.

Comment: now it does, and it is better again so removed the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r.members.each do |m|
  r.public_send("#{m}=", " ") if r.public_send(m).to_s.empty?
end
```

Comment: That was quick ! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Struct` with a block and override the reader's with default's:

```
s = Struct.new(:datum, :string1, :string2, :string3, :nummer) do
  BLANK = " ".freeze
  def datum
    return BLANK if nil_or_empty?(values[0])
    values[0]
  end

  def string1
    return BLANK if nil_or_empty?(values[1])
    values[1]
  end

  def string2
    return BLANK if nil_or_empty?(values[2])
    values[2]
  end

  def string3
    return BLANK if nil_or_empty?(values[3])
    values[3]
  end

  def nummer
    return BLANK if nil_or_empty?(values[4])
    values[4]
  end

  def nil_or_empty?(val)
    val.nil? || val.empty?
  end
end



r = s.new(Time.now(), "", "test", nil, 0.0)
p r.string3
p r.string1
```

outputs:

```
" "
" "
```

Comment: Thanks Antony but the Struct in reality has +30 members, a bit cumbersome and  bloated..

Comment: This implementation has a glitch: `r.string1 << "!"` fails, plus all `BLANK`s are the same shared frozen string. See my adoption for the correct implementation.

Comment: The original question didn't mention anything about whether the values of the struct need to be mutable so I'm not sure if the scenario you are proposing is real (for the author).  I don't understand you're point about `BLANK` either.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the answer by @Anthony to be more robust:

```
s = Struct.new(:datum, :string1, :string2, :string3, :nummer) do
  BLANK = " ".freeze
  members.each_with_index do |m, idx|
    define_method m do
      self.[]=(idx, BLANK.dup) if values[idx].to_s.empty?
      values[idx]
    end
  end
end

r = s.new(Time.now(), "", "test", nil, 0.0)
p r.string3
#⇒ " "
p r.string1
#⇒ " "
```

Comment: tested this but I get a nil and an empty string, Ruby 1.9.3 the cause ?

Comment: I have just realized that `values` returns a copy of the real value. Fixed, please retest.

Comment: yep, works now, thanks again, only caveat is you see this only when you ask for the value like that, not when you use inspect to view the contents

Comment: That’s the main reason I decided to publish this separately. The approach in my first answer is _explicit_. This one is _lazily implicit_. Unless it’s needed, it’s not touched.